React Native iCloud Keychain popup not appearing after 2FA
I have a React Native app built with Expo and Expo Router. I've correctly configured autofill, and it works perfectly. On my Login screen, when I enter the username and password correctly, I get a successful response from my API and navigate to the next screen, and the iCloud Keychain popup to save my credentials appears as expected.
However, sometimes my API returns an error code when logging in, which means the user needs to enter a 2FA code. After entering the 2FA code, I press the login button again and navigate to the next screen successfully, but now the iCloud Keychain popup never appears.
Does anyone have any idea why this might be happening?
It seems like if the response from the API is not successful the iCloud popup does not appear anymore.
This issue occurs on both iOS and Android.
EDIT:
I've realised that the issue only happens when the focus is in the OTP code input. If I switch the focus to the username or password inputs it works...
Here is my code:
import theme from '@config/theme';
import { router } from 'expo-router';
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { Button, StyleSheet, Text, TextInput, View } from 'react-native';
import Toast from 'react-native-toast-message';

import { useSignIn } from '../hooks';
import { ErrorApiResponse, SignInForm } from '../types';

const SignInScreen = () => {
  const { login } = useSignIn();
  const [isOtpCodeRequired, setIsOtpCodeRequired] = useState(false);

  const [email, setEmail] = useState('');
  const [password, setPassword] = useState('');
  const [otpCode, setOtpCode] = useState('');

  const handleOnSignIn = async ({ email, password, otpCode }: SignInForm) => {
    try {
      await login({
        email,
        password,
        otpAttempt: otpCode,
      });
      router.navigate('/home');
    } catch (error) {
      const typedError = error as ErrorApiResponse;
      if (
        typedError?.response?.status === 401 &&
        typedError?.response?.data?.errorCode === 12345
      ) {
        setIsOtpCodeRequired(true);
      } else {
        Toast.show({
          type: 'error',
          text1: 'Login Error',
          text2: typedError?.response?.data?.error,
        });
      }
    }
  };

  return (
    <View style={styles.mainContainer}>
      <View style={styles.formContainer}>
        <View style={{}}>
          <Text>Email</Text>
          <TextInput
            value={email}
            onChangeText={setEmail}
            placeholder="Email"
            keyboardType="email-address"
            textContentType="emailAddress"
            style={styles.input}
          />
        </View>

        <View style={{}}>
          <Text>Password</Text>
          <TextInput
            value={password}
            onChangeText={setPassword}
            placeholder="Password"
            secureTextEntry
            textContentType="password"
            style={styles.input}
          />
        </View>

        {isOtpCodeRequired && (
          <View style={{}}>
            <Text>Otp Code</Text>
            <TextInput
              placeholder="OTP CODE"
              value={otpCode}
              onChangeText={setOtpCode}
              textContentType="oneTimeCode"
              style={styles.input}
            />
          </View>
        )}
      </View>

      <View style={styles.buttonContainer}>
        <Button
          title="Log in"
          onPress={() => handleOnSignIn({ email, password, otpCode })}
        />
      </View>
    </View>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  mainContainer: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'space-between',
    paddingHorizontal: theme.sizes.dimensions.padding * 2,
  },
  formContainer: { marginTop: 46 },
  input: {
    borderWidth: 1,
    borderColor: theme.colors.gray500,
    padding: 8,
    borderRadius: 8,
  },
  buttonContainer: {
    marginBottom: theme.sizes.dimensions.padding * 2,
  },
});

export default SignInScreen;

